# HTML/CSS Space Between 2 Divs

Tags: html, css

I looked across the web for an answer to my question but most of the returns to my queries were asking the opposite of my question which seems to be more of a common problem. I want to separate two divs with a 20 pixel space so that the divs appear as 2 rectangles rather than one.

Here is my CSS:

```
#balances {
font-family:Lato;
background-color:#00253F;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-size:28px;
padding-left:15px;
font-weight:bold;
padding-right:10px;
padding-top:15px;
height:130px;
width:52%;
float:left;
}

#transact {
font-family:Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
background-color:#00253F;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-size:28px;
padding-left:15px;
font-weight:bold;
padding-right:10px;
padding-top:15px;
height:130px;
width:52%;
float:left;
}
```

this is the HTML:

```
<body>
     <div id="main-page-content">

          <div id="balances">
                <u>Balances</u>
                <div class="total-balance">Total Balance</div>


                <div class="balance">Balance:
                     <a href="#" class="button"/>Deposit</a>
                     <a href="#" class="button"/>Withdraw</a>
                </div>

                <div class="fbalance">
                     <a href="#" class="button"/>Deposit</a>
                     <a href="#" class="button"/>Withdraw</a> 
                </div>

          </div>

          <div id="transact">

          </div>

     </div>
</body>
```

The result of the above:
[image: Result of the code I've given]

Comment: Which `div` elements are you wanting to separate?

Comment: just seeing the code its seems you need to give space between `<a>` tag. so give margin for `a` tag. you can try like this `.balance > a:last-child{
  margin:0 0 0 15px; color:red; }` check Demo. http://jsbin.com/vuhulopimo/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Margin will do that for you: http://jsfiddle.net/pybkpoev/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty simple using `margin`, there are many ways to do it but I went with the simple way of putting a class on button 2 and setting `margin-left: 20px;`.

If you don't want to add a class you can use `:nth-child(n)`(or other selectors, find more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30071396/2259322)), note that this is using CSS3. More on that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

```css
.button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
}
.button2 {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Button 1</div>
<div class="button button2">Button 2</div>
```

---

Using the code you provided and using `nth-child(n)`, you can do it like this.

```css
.balance a:nth-child(2) {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.fbalance a:nth-child(2) {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#balances {
    font-family:Lato;
    background-color:#00253F;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:28px;
    padding-left:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-top:15px;
    height:130px;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
#transact {
    font-family:Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
    background-color:#00253F;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:28px;
    padding-left:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-top:15px;
    height:130px;
    width:52%;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="balances"> <u>Balances</u>
    <div class="total-balance">Total Balance</div>
    <div class="balance">Balance: 
        <a href="#" class="button">Deposit</a>
        <a href="#" class="button">Withdraw</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="fbalance">
        <a href="#" class="button">Deposit</a>
        <a href="#" class="button">Withdraw</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why you are using `nth-chiild` ? we can simply use `last-child` in this case.

Comment: @KheemaPandey Was trying to keep it simple, the OP didn't know how to use `margin` why would I confuse them more with all kinds of different selectors. Its only an example.

Answer (score 0):

Add margin to the divs in which you want space simple.